# z3 timeout on linux/mac

Tags: z3

Hi Leonardo: Looks like z3 (v3.2) accepts the command line switch "-T:10" for specifying time-outs on Mac and Linux, but ignores it. (Haven't tried on windows.) It'd be really nice if timeouts were supported on linux/mac releases as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `-T` switch is Windows only in Z3 3.2. This will be fixed in the next release.