# Am I using z3 :timeout correctly with C++ interface for Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, z3

I'm trying to get the z3 solver to timeout after 0.1s on this example (factoring a 32-bit product of two primes), using the C++ interface.  It works on Windows (VC++ 2013), but not on Linux (CentOS 6.5), where the solver runs to completion in around 2.5s (debug build).  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273091/z3-timeout-on-linux-mac) indicates that the command-line timeout was only supported on Windows back in 2012 with z3 v3.2, but this was supposed to be fixed in the next release - we're using z3 v4.4, according to the RELEASE_NOTES.  Am I using the timeout functionality correctly for the C++ interface, or is this not supported on Linux?

(Note: this code sample uses the concat definition from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135216/is-there-a-form-of-bitvector-concat-in-the-z3-c-interface). The TEST, EXPECT_EQ, and EXPECT_TRUE macros are gtest testing macros, that should be self-explanatory.)

```
    TEST(Z3Basic, Factorize32BitWithTimeout) {
    try {
        context c;
        solver s(c);

        expr x = c.bv_const("x", 16);
        expr y = c.bv_const("y", 16);
        expr prod = c.bv_val(0xc4f7d27bll, 32);

        expr pad = c.bv_val(0, 16);

        params p(c);
        p.set(":timeout", 100u);
        s.set(p);
        expr conjecture = prod == concat(pad, x) * concat(pad, y);
        s.add(conjecture);
        check_result r = s.check();
        EXPECT_EQ(unknown, r);
        if (r == sat)
            std::cout << s.get_model() << "\n";
    }
    catch (exception ex) {
        EXPECT_TRUE(false) << "Exception thrown: " << ex << "\n";
    }

}
```

On Windows debug, this runs the whole test in around 210ms, and passes with an unknown return code.  On Linux, it runs to completion and fails:

```
[ RUN      ] Z3Basic.Factorize32BitWithTimeout
/home/dave_local/Projects/trunk/CoreApp/z3Interface/UnitTests/TestZ3.cpp:492: Failure
Value of: r
  Actual: sat
Expected: unknown
(define-fun y () (_ BitVec 16)
  #xd279)
(define-fun x () (_ BitVec 16)
  #xef93)
[  FAILED  ] Z3Basic.Factorize32BitWithTimeout (2565 ms)
```

Any suggestions/information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeout through the API is definitely supported. Maybe 100ms on your Linux box is too much?  Can you try with a smaller timeout?

If it still fails, could you file a bug report with a short, self-contained, reproducing test case? Thanks!

Comment: I've reduced the timeout down to 1ms (set timeout to 1u instead of 100u) with the same results - it still completes after about 2.5s.  I'm working on translating this into an SMT2 example that could be run through the standalone z3, although the code above could probably be added to the c++ examples file (just strip out the gtest macros) to demonstrate the problem.  I assume the former would be preferred in filing a bug report - is this correct?

Comment: Turning this into a self-contained reproducing test case revealed that the timeout worked when built as part of the z3 examples, but not in our build environment.  The difference was due to compile flag differences - you need to use the <underscore>LINUX<underscore> compile flag (not just _LINUX) when compiling src/util/scoped_timer.cpp  to get the timeouts to work properly on Linux (where <underscore> represents an actual underscore character, which gets turned into italic formatting if I put it here literally).

Comment: There was indeed a typo in our build scripts.  I've fixed it here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/commit/e441db5bc424113c552ac258c454ed8ff1c9e394